# Change td color depends on status

Tags: php, css

If i want to change bgcolor on whole tr, its work.

```
    if ($sta =="1"){
            print("<tr bgcolor=#2E0854>\n");
        }
    if ($sta =="2"){
            print("<tr bgcolor=#000000>\n");
        }

    print("<td>$sta</td>\n");
    print("<td>$name</td>\n");
    print("<td>$info</td>\n");
    print("<td>$day</td>\n");
    print("</tr>\n");
    }
```

But when i try to change td color on only one td, i cant make it work

```
     if ($sta =="1"){
            echo "<style type='text/css'>
            td.farg {
                background-color: #2E0854;
            }
            </style>";
        }
     if ($sta =="2"){
            echo "<style type='text/css'>
            td.farg {
                background-color: #000000;
            }
            </style>";
        }



    print("<td>$sta</td>\n");
    print("<td class='farg'>$name</td>\n");
    print("<td>$info</td>\n");
    print("<td>$day</td>\n");
    print("</tr>\n");
    }
```

It gives same td color for all even tho some has status 1 and some status 2

Comment: In CSS, use `background-color`. Cheers.

Comment: Where is your opening **tr** tag?

Comment: If this code supposed to be in a loop?

Comment: yes this code is in a loop

Comment: but didnt want to post any unessesary code

Comment: You can't give them all the same class if they're supposed to have different colors. If they're identical the browser can't know which ones should have which color. You'll have to give something like "farg1" class for status 1 and "farg2" class for status 2 and set the colors of those classes in the CSS.

Comment: The information that this is in a loop is not "unnecessary." It's the most important part of the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better to work with dynamic css class names instead of change the color directly.

**CSS:**

```
tr.sta-1 {
    background-color: #2E0854;
}
tr.sta-2 {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

or for td:

```
tr.sta-1 td.farg {
    background-color: #2E0854;
}
tr.sta-2 td.farg {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

**PHP:**

```
print("<tr class=\"sta-$sta\">\n");
print("<td>$sta</td>\n");
print("<td class=\"farg\">$name</td>\n");
print("<td>$info</td>\n");
print("<td>$day</td>\n");
print("</tr>\n");
```

Comment: will this solve the td problem you mean? or do i just need to change it to td.sta-1

Comment: I've added the part for `td` to my answer.